# ERRO DE INVALID SYNTAX

Tags: python, syntax-error

O código abaixo está dando erro de `invalid syntax`.

Segue:

```
while(escolha!=0 and confirmar!=0):
    print("Menu")
    print("1- Inserir um item")
    print("2- Remover item")
    print("3- Listar todos os itens")
    print("4- Buscar um item")
    print("5- Atualizar dados de um item")
    print("6- Limpar tela")
    print("0- Sair do programa")
    if(escolha==1): #Inserir um item
        aux = ficha ( )
        aux.cpf=input('Informe o cpf do cliente: ')
        aux.nome=input('informe o nome do cliente: ')
        aux.nasc=input('informe a data de nascimento do cliente: ')
        aux.email=input('informe o email do cliente: ')
        aux.telefone=input('informe o telefone do cliente: ')   
    elif(escolha==2): #remover um item
                busca=input('informe o cpf para a procura: ')
                for i in lista #laço para busca do cpf ##<--AQUI DA ERRO DE INVALID SYNTAX
                if(busca == i.cpf):
                        confirmar=input('Digite 1 para confirmar a exclusão, 0 para negar')
                        if(confirmar==1): #condicional para verificar a decisão quanto a exclusão
                                print("CPF encontrado e dados apagados")
                                lista.remove(i)
                                busca_positiva=1
                    elif:
                        print("Exclusão negada")
                elif:
                    continue
```

Comment: Que linguagem é isso? Onde ocorre o erro? Edite a pergunta e forneça mais detalhes, sua pergunta está vaga demais.

Comment: Não sei muito de python, mas acho que o erro é ter um elif sem a verificação

Comment: Sobre [controle de fluxo](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Comment: Sua identação também está inconsistente, isso na syntax do Python

Comment: Erro de indentação não pode porque o python mesmo que automaticamente colocou nesse formato eu so fui dando enter sem alterar espaços

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse seria o seu código sem os erros:

```
while(escolha!=0 and confirmar!=0):
    print("Menu")
    print("1- Inserir um item")
    print("2- Remover item")
    print("3- Listar todos os itens")
    print("4- Buscar um item")
    print("5- Atualizar dados de um item")
    print("6- Limpar tela")
    print("0- Sair do programa")
    if(escolha==1): #Inserir um item
        aux = ficha ( )
        aux.cpf=input('Informe o cpf do cliente: ')
        aux.nome=input('informe o nome do cliente: ')
        aux.nasc=input('informe a data de nascimento do cliente: ')
        aux.email=input('informe o email do cliente: ')
        aux.telefone=input('informe o telefone do cliente: ')   
    elif(escolha==2): #remover um item
        busca=input('informe o cpf para a procura: ')
        for i in lista: #laço para busca do cpf ##<--AQUI DA ERRO DE INVALID SYNTAX
            if(busca == i.cpf):
                confirmar=input('Digite 1 para confirmar a exclusão, 0 para negar')
                if(confirmar==1): #condicional para verificar a decisão quanto a exclusão
                    print("CPF encontrado e dados apagados")
                    lista.remove(i)
                    busca_positiva=1
                else:
                    print("Exclusão negada")
            else:
                continue
```

O primeiro erro é referente a linha `for i in lista`, é necessário um `:` no final da linha, outros problemas estão relacionados aos `elif`'s sem uma verificação, se você quer executar algo caso o `if` falhe e não haja outra verificação deve ser usado o `else`.

Obs.: Em Python a identação conta como parte da sintaxe, ela deve ser consistente, não misture espaços com tabs, ou use o tamanho incorreto de caracteres.

Comment: Denis voce é o cara.

Comment: Resolveu mesmo, muito obrigado pelo rápido retorno

Comment: Você pode [marcar a resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.